Patroni max_connections parameter not reflecting in PostgreSQL configuration"
The problem i am  facing with the max_connections setting not reflecting the expected value can be described as follows:
Expected Configuration: In my Patroni configuration (/etc/patroni.yml), i have set max_connections to 3000.
Actual PostgreSQL Configuration: However, when i check the max_connections setting in PostgreSQL using SHOW max_connections;, it shows a value of 100 instead of the expected 3000.
i have attempted to modify the max_connections setting using ALTER SYSTEM SET max_connections = 125; followed by pg_reload_conf(); to apply the changes. Despite these actions, the max_connections value remains at 100.
what may be the possible cause i have 3 nodes of patroni and one etcd and one haproxy

may you defined the max_connections in wrong place in /etc/patroni.yml file, can you provide the Patroni configuration file.

Use the patronictl edit-config to add the postgres parameter.
ref: https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/How-to-set-GUCs-in-patroni-cluster?language=en_US
